# .appendChild() an HTML element on click

Tags: javascript, jquery, appendchild

I wanted to copy an entire row including its' siblings and contents on button click. When I click the button the element, it appears in the console but doesn't append to the page. This is my code:

It doesn't show any error messages. I've tried innerHTML/outerHTML or append() it doesn't work.

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    $('#addSubFBtn').on('click', function() {
        var itm = document.getElementById("trFb");
        var wrapper = document.createElement('div');
        var el = wrapper.appendChild(itm);
        document.getElementById("tbFb").append(el);
        console.log(el);
    });
});
```

Comment: It'd be good to see even a portion of the HTML to get further context, when you inspect the element 'tbFb' using dev tools is there any child element existing? It'd be good to have a demonstration here: https://jsfiddle.net/

Answer (score 1):

Seems like what you're trying to do is clone the item after you get it from your document. W3schools website explains how to accomplish this. Check out the link: https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_node_clonenode.asp

Once you clone the node, [appendchild] should work as intended

Answer (score 0):

Not sure (as said without seeing related HTML) but i see flaw in your logic:

`var itm = document.getElementById("trFb");`
still exist on the document(so in the page) so you've to retrieve it before you want to add/move it to another place.
using .removeElement will return you removed element(or null if no element matche the selector) so correct script should be:

`var itm=document.getElementById("trFb").parentNode.removeChild(document.getElementById("trFb"));`
as shown here to remove element you've to use method on to parent element.
So you can add it to any other element existing.
For more specific use or element created in global JS variable (such an createElement not yet appended) you can see :`document.createDocumentFragment();` as explained here https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/createDocumentFragment